# How to create Advanced FIlters Over SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, filter, advanced-filter

I have a database of Candidates which holds basic candidate information in one table and other related details such as
1. Educational Qualifications
2. Skills
3. Interest
... and others

How to do a bolean filter across all these data.

Comment: JOIN and use WHERE..

Comment: the education table contains multiple records per candidate. how to handle that?

Comment: how far have you got? it would be easier to answer from a position of some existing code that shows the broad approach you're using - there are *tons* of ways of doing data access, and how to filter depends on the approach used.

Comment: @piresashwin if multiplicity is a problem: then either `EXISTS` or `DISTINCT`

Comment: @MarcGravell. Not yet started with the coding.But the database ready. need a best practice way to achieve the Boolean filters